# Auto Display Info window based on camera position in Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]

> I have a cross hair at the center of the screen as shown in the picture. The center position is obtained by getting the camera target. I want to display the info window of the marker when the cross hair comes over the marker(Without clicking the marker). Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: do you have any listener for the cross hair..?

Comment: No, but the cross hair at the center of the map. I can get the LatLng position at that spot.

Comment: Can you get the LatLng of the cross hair as it moves?

Answer (score 1):

if you have the coordinates of the cross hair, with a bit of markers caching and code you can do it:
you can get the location of the crosshair and check (marker by marker) the distance of the two locations by using the utility library:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/

```
public static double computeDistanceBetween(LatLng from,
                            LatLng to)
```

And get the nearest marker (if inside a specific range that you decide).
Having the marker, just call the method

```
marker.showInfoWindow()
```

and you should be ok!
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#showInfoWindow()

Comment: I have a huge number of markers on the map. If i check the distance between each marker and cross hair, does it affects the performance of my application?

Comment: Is of course. You have no other convenient method, maybe emulate a touch on the screen in that point, but I don't know if is possible... There are no methods for this task!